# Swift zoom with scrollview not centered

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

When setting (selected by taking a picture) the image of my imageview (which is inside a scrollview) is set but a little to the right and not centered as is supposed to be

Im not using storyboard, everything is made programmatically

//creating frames
    imgBorder.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width * 0.7,     height: view.bounds.size.height * 0.7)
        imgBorder.center.x = self.view.bounds.width * 0.5
        imgBorder.center.y = self.view.bounds.height * 0.5
        imgBorder.image = UIImage(named: "imageBorder")
        self.view.addSubview(imgBorder)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imgBorder)

```
    scrollImg.delegate = self
    scrollImg.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width * 0.5 -     imgBorder.frame.size.width/2, y: view.bounds.size.height * 0.5 - imgBorder.frame.size.height/2, width: imgBorder.bounds.size.width, height: imgBorder.bounds.size.height)
    scrollImg.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollImg.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

    self.view.addSubview(scrollImg)

    imgPicture.frame.size = scrollImg.frame.size
    imgPicture.center.x = scrollImg.center.x
    imgPicture.center.y = scrollImg.center.y

    scrollImg.addSubview(imgPicture)
```

First image shows when i take the picture (the problem in this post)
Second shows the picture im taking
Third shows that zoom is working fine with border limits
[image: image after taking a picture]

[image: picture taken]

[image: zoom working fine]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem removing these lines of code:

```
imgPicture.center.x = scrollImg.center.x
imgPicture.center.y = scrollImg.center.y
```